# upgrade spring boot 2.7.0, do I need to also upgrade all the Managed Dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am upgrading to spring boot 2.7.0 do I need to also upgrade all the Managed Dependencies mentioned in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.7.0 in my project also ?

Thanks

Comment: When you manage them, you should! When spring-boot manages, you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade the spring boot parent version and let it handle its related dependencies
Read these points:

1. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent#spring-boot-starter-parent
2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent#managing-dependencies